# Proof that the set of incompressible strings is undecidable

Tags: computability, kolmogorov-complexity

I would like to see a proof or a sketch of a proof that the set of incompressible strings is undecidable.

Definition: Let x be a string, we say that x is c-compressible if K(x) $\leq$ |x|-c.
If x is not c-compressible, we say that x is incompressible by c. K(x) represents the Kolmogorov complexity of a binary string x.

Theorem: incompressible strings of every length exist.

Proof: The number of binary strings of length n is $2^{n}$, but there exist
$\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1} 2^i$=$2^{n}$-1 descriptions of lengths that is less than n. Since each description describes at most one string then there is at least one string of length n that is incompressible.

From here I feel it is natural to ask whether or not the set of incompressible strings is decidable, the answer is $\textit{no}$, but I would like to see the justification via a proof or proof sketch.

Edit: I would like to add I am already familiar/comfortable with the proof that Kolmogorov complexity is uncomputable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roughly speaking, incompressibility is undecidable because of a version of the [Berry paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry_paradox).  Specifically, if incompressibility were decidable, we could specify "the lexicographically first incompressible string of length 1000" with the description in quotes, which has length less than 1000.

For a more precise proof of this, consider the [Wikipedia proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity#Incomputability_of_Kolmogorov_complexity) that $K$ is not computable.  We can modify this proof as follows to show that incompressibility is undecidable.  Suppose we have a function `IsIncompressible` that checks whether a given string is incompressible.  Since there is always at least one incompressible string of length $n$, the function `GenerateComplexString` that the Wikipedia article describes can be modified as follows:

```
function GenerateComplexString(int n)
    for each string s of length exactly n
       if IsIncompressible(s)
          return s
          quit
```

This function uses `IsIncompressible` to produce roughly the same result that the `KolmogorovComplexity` function is used for in the Wikipedia article.  The argument that this leads to a contradiction now goes through almost verbatim.